# Moving files from one Team Foundation Project to Another

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

Our project has hit a point where we need to split off some code into a separate team foundation project.  We would like to move these files so they retain their version control history.  Temporarily we are copying the files back to the original team foundation project and re-adding them just so that our daily build & test process doesn't break. As we are able to modify our build & test process we will start to remove these temporary copies.

One issue we are noticing is that we have a nightly script that checks various maintenance branches to see if there are changesets that haven't been merged back to trunk.  It is now whining about changesets that *have* been merged before.  These changesets seem to be related to the files that have been moved and re-added.  Any ideas as to why we are seeing this and how we can discard these merge candidates?  If we do a merge /discard TF tells us "there are no changes to merge".  It seems to be confused.  Also are there other problems we might run into with this approach?  Perhaps there is a better approach?

Comment: Which TFS version are you using? TFS2010 can branch and merge across Team Projects as long as they are in the same Project Collection.

Comment: What is the real need for a second Team Project? Normally you should be able to get very far by creating root level folders for Area, Iteration and Source Control and be able to keep multiple Visual Studio projects in the same Team Project. See also: http://www.andygeldman.com/index.php/2012/01/perils-of-multiple-project-collections-and-team-projects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was to merge /discard all other changesets, then do a "catchup" merge /discard i.e. not specifying any version info.  This generated a number of merge related pending changes but when I went to check them in, I got a TF14088 error.  The workaround for this error was to checkin *just* the problematic files/folders first and then check in everything else.