# Team Foundation Server 2008: How to move files from one Project to another.

Tags: file, projects

I am using Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2008, and am preparing to merge several TFS projects together, and I'd like to do this in the best way possible. All of these projects are within a single TFS instance.

I merging projects because the product line that is contained in all of the projects is small and is worked on by a single, small team, and so the projects themselves are simply unnecessary. Thus, I am trying to simplify our structure by merging the projects together. What this amounts to, I think, is a need to move the files from all projects into just one of the projects. But, I want to do this without affecting file history, etc.

I have tried researching this, and have found the following resources:

- [Moving files from one Team Foundation Project to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149919/moving-files-from-one-team-foundation-project-to-another)
- [Moving files between projects in Solution Explorer removes source
  control history, breaking merge capabilities](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949476)

The second resource, a Microsoft knowledge base article, actually looks pretty useful. But, before I dive into this, I am just wondering what advice and/or warnings the SO community might offer? I am just hoping to go into this with my "eyes wide open."

Comment: To avoid ambiguities: this is projects on the same TFS instance?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you for the clarifying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moves within Solution Explorer (and Solution Navigator from Productivity Power Tools) a move of a solution item will lead to a delete and add in version control.

But you can also move items either within Source Control Explorer or using `tf.exe`'s `move` command from the command line. The latter can, of course, be automated with in a script if there are many items to move.